# Al deseleccionar alguno de los checkbox, se borra todo el array que los muestra

Tags: javascript, html5

Esto me anda deteniendo en un proyecto sobre un sorteo de partidos de fútbol. Estoy desarrollando un script, donde al seleccionar varios checkbox se guardan en un array (se llama *listArray* y estos guardan el valor *L*, *E* ó *V* respectivamente) y a su vez muestre el valor del checkbox seleccionado (en *valuelist1*). Hasta esta parte todo bien, solo que al deseleccionar alguno de los checkbox se borra todo el array que los muestra.

Como nota al margen, tuve que llamar a todos los checkbox de la misma manera (*checkboxp1*) para poder juntar los valores en una sola etiqueta que como mencioné arriba, se llama *valueList1*.

Copio el código a continuación:

```
var valuelist1 = document.getElementById('valueList1');
var listArrayP1 = [];  

var checkboxes1 = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxp1');
for (var checkbox1 of checkboxes1){
    checkbox1.addEventListener('click',function(){
        if(this.checked == true){
            listArrayP1.push(this.value);
            valuelist1.innerHTML = listArrayP1.join('');
            
        } else {
            listArrayP1=listArrayP1.filter(e=> e!== this.value);
            valuelist1.innerHTML = listArrayP1.join ('');
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

disculpa pero con lo que explicas no le veo fallo a tu codigo, hice un snippet mas o menos con lo que entendi de funcionalidad que explicas y no me da problemas.

```js
  var valuelist1 = document.getElementById('valueList1');
     var listArrayP1 = [];  

     var checkboxes1 = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxp1');
     for (var checkbox1 of checkboxes1){
          checkbox1.addEventListener('click',function(){
               if(this.checked == true){
                    listArrayP1.push(this.value);
                    valuelist1.innerHTML = listArrayP1.join('');
                    
               } else {
                    listArrayP1=listArrayP1.filter(e=> e!== this.value);
                    valuelist1.innerHTML = listArrayP1.join('');
               }
          })
     }
```

```html
<label>Seleccionado</label>
<div id="valueList1"></div>
<input type="checkbox" value="L" class="checkboxp1"> L
<input type="checkbox" value="E" class="checkboxp1"> E
<input type="checkbox" value="V" class="checkboxp1"> V
```

O a lo mejor entendi mal la funcionalidad, saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por responder. De hecho así lo tengo hecho, solo que el div en realidad es una tabla para dar formato visual al sorteo. Y como dices funciona. Mi problema deriva cuando llamo más información de los siguientes checkbox ya que el proyecto necesita 30, entonces al trabajar sobre el mismo script, si despliega la información correctamente, pero al borrar un check simulando que el usuario cambie de opinión en alguno de los partidos me borra todo lo que ya había desplegado en el array.

Comment: y todos esos checkbox comparten el mismo name? o es diferente cada uno?

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por responder. He hecho diversas pruebas, con el mismo name y cambiandolo tanto en el html como en el script y he obtenido el mismo resultado. Despliega correctamente la información pero al borrar algún check se borra todo y solo deja la coma que los separaba.

Answer (score 0):

¿cómo estas? Hay un par de cosas que no entiendo del contexto mas que todo. Quisiera entender si hay algun evento que dispara el resultado de ese array, o sea donde se utilzia ese array y cuando y porque se hace ese for.

Creo que mejor seria que lo hagas en un objeto mas que en un array.

```
let objeto= {
l: false,
e: false,
v: false
```

}

creo que es mucho mas facil declarar el objeto de forma global y configrar el valor de L,E,V en true y false dependiendo de lo que seleccione el usuario y en donde uses el obj solo le haces caso a los valores en true

Espero tu repuesta para tener mas contexto y poder ayudarte mas!!

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo y realmente soy nuevo en JS, no habia entendido bien la sintaxis en la pagina para compartir el codigo y no habia desplegado una variable al comienzo. 
Basicamente la llamada a la acción es el mismo clic que recibe el checkbox.
Se recibe el valor del checkbox de todos los que llevan el mismo nombre que se declaro en la var checkboxes1.
El for lo que hace es, mediante el clic que recibe el llama a la funcion click, lo que va imprimiendo los valores recibidos dentro del array.
y el else, lo que hacia era borrar la deseleccion del check en caso de cambiar de valor.

Comment: claro, o sea que el trigger por asi decirlo es el evento de click en cada uno de los checkbox? creo que lo mas conveniente, si esa info se debe enviar a otro lado, seria hacer un boton de "enviar" y que el evento sea el click de ese boton, entonces simplemente sacas los valores de los check y los metes en el objeto como true o false. por ejemplo, si L es el unico seleccionado, en el obj L: true y el resto false. Aun no entiendo cual es la finalidad del array.

Comment: Así es, el for recorre todos los checkbox. Y el array es solo para almacenar el valor obtenido por el recorrido del for y poder visualizar el grupo de datos recabados y después de ahí, está información del array sería enviada como cadena de texto por un URL de WhatsApp. Por eso es que pensé en array para trabajarlo pero parece ser complicado cada que lo sigo analizando jeje.